# Cannot set state to location.pathname in React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to set the state of my component to the current pathname of the URL. Specifically, I want to do this in my ResponsiveDrawer component defined in App.js as:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <ResponsiveDrawer>
          <div className="App">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Administrator} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Administrator} />
            <Route exact path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
            <Route path="/jobs/:id" render={({match}) => <ViewJob id={match.params.id} />} />
            <Route path="/entries/:jobId/:entryId" render={({match}) => <Entry jobId={match.params.jobId} entryId={match.params.entryId} />} />
            <Route exact path="/reports" component={Reports} />
            <Route path="/reports/:jobId" render={({match}) => <JobReport id={match.params.jobId} />} />
            <Route path="/reports/activity" component={ActivityReport} />
          </div>
         </ResponsiveDrawer>
     </Router>

    );
  }
}
```

Now, in the ResponsiveDrawer component I have the following code to that should trigger when the URL changes:

```
class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      mobileOpen: false,
      adminOpen: true,
      jobsOpen: false,
      reportsOpen: false,
      activePath: ''
    };
    this.setActiveState = this.setActiveState.bind(this);
    this.isActiveFunc = this.isActiveFunc.bind(this);
  }


  setActiveState = (path) => {
    this.setState({activePath: path});
  };

  isActiveFunc = (match, location) => {
    console.log(location.pathname)
    this.setActiveState(location.pathname);
    return match
  };

  render() {  
      <NavLink isActive={this.isActiveFunc} className={classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: "/admin/users" }}>
         <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
         <ListItemText inset primary="Users" />
         </ListItem>
       </NavLink>
```

This correctly logs the current location every time the NavLink is clicked. However, when I try to set the state to the value of the location.pathname I get the following error:

> proxyConsole.js:54 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

And my browser goes into an infinite loop and crashes

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the `NavLink` component, it looks like it is immediately invoking the function passed in on `isActive` prop?

Comment: I import it from the router (see here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can see from this line,

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js#L34

That the function passed in on `isActive` is immediately invoked in the `NavLink` render function.

`setState` is obviously should not be used in the `render` because that could cause an infinite render loop.

You should look to use `componentWillReceiveProps` instead.

Comment: Thanks! The easiest solution for me would be having the state always be set to this.location.pathname. However, I somehow don't have access to that property in my component

Comment: It seems that the issue is that my ResponsiveDrawer component is outside the <Route /> scope and therefore I cannot access this.props.params.match. Is there any way around this?

Comment: window.location seems to work, but it doesn't update when I click a new component. Ideally I would want something similar to subscribing for router changes that you might know from Angular